# How to make FloatingActionButton a Square with the Material Library?

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, android-styles, floating-action-button

I'm trying to make by `FloatingActionButton` a square using the material library in my styles:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">`

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I customize a Floating Action Button shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59901825/how-do-i-customize-a-floating-action-button-shape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ExtendedFloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/floatingactionbutton/ExtendedFloatingActionButton) with 0dp corners

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/SquareFAB" />
```

In styles.xml or themes.xml:

```
<style name="SquareFAB" parent="">
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
</style>
```

UPDATE:

> But I want it the same size as my mini fab button i.imgur.com/Qg9kzdu.png which has the attribute app:fabSize="mini"

[As per documentation](https://material.io/components/buttons-floating-action-button), the `mini` size of the FAB is 40dp; so you can adjust that as width & height:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/SquareFAB" />
```

Comment: But I want it the same size as my mini fab button https://i.imgur.com/Qg9kzdu.png which has the attribute app:fabSize="mini"